# Installing Python Libraries in VM Instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have created a VM Instance on Google Cloud, and wrote some code in it. I import a library in my code which has not been installed in the VM instance. How can I install the library in the VM Instance now?

Google searches show links to install python packages in notebooks but none of them explain how to do it in VM Instances.

Comment: Can you detail your question? What your error ? Are you writing python code or Jupyter notebook? detail exactly your steps for a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

### Google Cloud Shell

If you are trying to install Python dependencies within your GCE instance, I would just SSH into your instance, then once inside the Cloud Shell, install **`pip`**, which is Python's package manager, using the following commands:

```
sudo curl "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "get-pip.py"
sudo python get-pip.py
```

After this, for example, if you would like to import Beautifulsoup library (or any other library) in your code, you would run the following command in the command line to install the library:

```
sudo pip install beautifulsoup4
```

### In your code

Just import the following in your Python code to have access to the library:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: Heya @Vivek!

If this answer worked out for you, could you accept it so that it has better visibility on the community? It will help other users that run into the same situation =)!