# Google Cloud Run Flask App error import module

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-run

I have developed a flask rest API and I'm using flask_smorest.
I'm developing into cloud shell editor into google cloud.
When I run google cloud run emulator, I receive the error:

```
##########Linting Output - pylint##########
************* Module app
3,0,error,import-error:Unable to import 'flask_smorest'
```

and this my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

ENV APP_HOME /app 
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

RUN pip install Flask gunicorn flask-smorest marshmallow

CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 app:app
```

This is app.py file:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_smorest import Api


app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS"] = True
app.config["API_TITLE"] = "Stores REST API"
app.config["API_VERSION"] = "v1"
app.config["OPENAPI_VERSION"] = "3.0.3"
app.config["OPENAPI_URL_PREFIX"] = "/"
app.config["OPENAPI_SWAGGER_UI_PATH"] = "/swagger-ui"
app.config["OPENAPI_SWAGGER_UI_URL"] ="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swagger-ui-dist/"




if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8080)))
```

how i can fix this issue? And why i have this error?

Comment: Looks like 'google cloud run emulator' don't deal with docker, you need to install libs directly see receipt here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57951123/installing-python-libraries-in-vm-instance

Comment: I'm unable to repro your issue. Although your `app.py` does not appear to do anything, I'm able to deploy the code as shown. Does the working directory (from which you're running `gcloud beta code dev` include `app.py` and `Dockerfile` as shown above?

Comment: Just to double check, is your file called "dockerfile" or "Dockerfile"? It's case-sensitive, so if it's not called `Dockerfile` and you didn't pass the `--dockerfile=` flag to `gcloud beta code dev`, it's not going to find it so it won't be building your container correctly.

Comment: Can you also check if you either install the framework or it's added in your `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: Hi all, i have fix issue installing the module  from Cloud Shell Terminal. Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as a community wiki from [@dev_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4837637/dev):

> The issue was resolved by installing the module from the Cloud Shell Terminal.